# Need to calculate duration of business time not worked in previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server, calendar, duration

I need to be able to pull the amount of time *within business hours* an employee was off in the previous month.

*EX: if an employee was off from 8am Friday thru 5pm the following Monday, the 'DurationOff' for that instance would be 18 hours (based on business hours being Mon-Fri, 8am-5pm).*

The 2 bits of data I have are below & in [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0b289/46). Scripts can be provided if needed.

#1. TechTimeOff: Each instance a tech was off in previous month. The 'DurationOff' column is what I'm trying to achieve (in minutes or decimals).

| TechID | TechName | TimeOff_From | TimeOff_To | TimeOff_ID | From(MinuteOfTheMonth) | To(MinuteOfTheMonth) | *DurationOff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Beaver | 2023-02-01 08:00 | 2023-02-01 16:30 | 23 | 480 | 990 | 8.50 hrs (or 510 mins) |
| 2 | Wally | 2023-02-01 08:00 | 2023-02-03 17:00 | 24 | 480 | 3060 | 27.00 hrs (or 1620 mins) |
| 3 | Ward | 2023-02-01 08:00 | 2023-02-06 17:00 | 25 | 480 | 6120 | 36.00 hrs (or 2160 mins) |

#2. Calendar: Every minute in the previous month. BusinessTime = 'No' if that minute isn't within Business Hour parameters.
(only showing rows applicable to this post)

| Date&Time | DayName | MinuteOfTheMonth | HourOfTheDay | BusinessTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-01 07:59:00 | Wednesday | 479 | 7 | No |
| 2023-02-01 08:00:00 | Wednesday | 480 | 8 | Yes |
| 2023-02-01 16:30:00 | Wednesday | 990 | 16 | Yes |
| 2023-02-03 17:00:00 | Friday | 3060 | 17 | Yes |
| 2023-02-04 08:00:00 | Saturday | 1920 | 8 | No |
| 2023-02-06 17:00:00 | Monday | 6120 | 17 | Yes |

My plan was to add a new column ('MinuteOfTheMonth') to TechTimeOff that shows the minute of the month for every minute during the time off period. Then I could join TechTimeOff to Calendar on the MinuteOfTheMonth and filter out the minutes that aren't BusinessTime.

I just can't figure out how to break out the time off periods into rows by the minute.

So, I either need help with that, or suggestions on a better way to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since your Calendar table contains for every minute, you can just join to it and perform a `count(*)`, that is the duration you required in minutes

```
select  t.TechID, t.TechName, Duration = count(*)
from    TechTimeOff t
        inner join Calendar c   on  c.Day_Time >= t.TimeOff_From
                                and c.Day_Time <  t.TimeOff_To
where   c.BusinessTime  = 'Yes'
group by t.TechID, t.TechName;
```

Comment: No cigar, bummer! The 'Duration' values were (1,2,and 3). Not the values I'm aiming for (510,1620, and 2160). Any other thoughts?

Comment: I tweaked your code & tried this. It gave me total number of minutes (510, 2580, and 5640), but still isn't excluding minutes where BusinessTime LIKE 'No'.


'''select  
t.TechID
, t.TechName
, CASE WHEN c.businesstime like 'Yes' 
   THEN (t.To_MinuteOfTheMonth - t.From_MinuteOfTheMonth) end as 'Duration'

from TechTimeOff t
inner join Calendar c   on  c.Day_Time >= t.TimeOff_From
                        and c.Day_Time <=  t.TimeOff_To
                        and c.BusinessTime = 'Yes'

group by t.TechID, t.TechName,c.businesstime,t.From_MinuteOfTheMonth,t.To_MinuteOfTheMonth;'''

Comment: my query should works, if you do really have rows in the `Calendar` table by the minute ? Meaning you should have `24 x 60` rows for any day. I think you must have execute my query in your fiddle which only contains limited rows in the `calendar` table